# ssh-keygen -f confusion

Tags: unix, ssh

While trying to create rsa keypairs for a project inside the project dir I was experimenting with `ssh-keygen`'s `-f` option. When I test it in a freshly created directory everything works as expected, but when I try to use the exact same syntax on another equally permissioned directory `ssh-keygen` just keeps telling me `No such file or directory.`

In a way it is right saying so, because it is supposed to create these files. (The directory in which it shall work exists.)

The syntax I use for key creation is:

```
ssh-keygen -q -t rsa -f /abspath/id_rsa -N ""
```

Comment: is `/abspath/` an indication of the command or  is it what you actually typed?

Comment: /abspath/ is just meant to indicate that I used an absolute path to a folder there as is required by `ssh-keygen`

Answer (score 1):

I am not able to recreate this problem unless I specify a directory that does not actually exist. I suggest that you look at where you're trying to create the key pair, making sure that the directory exist.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create a directory to store your host key file:

```
$ mkdir -p $HOME/.ssh/mykey
```

Second, depending on which key type, you can reate a host key file in your `$HOME/.ssh/mykey` : (choose ONE)

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -f $HOME/.ssh/mykey/rsa_key_file
```

or

```
$ ssh-keygen -t dsa -f $HOME/.ssh/mykey/dsa_key_file
```

or

```
$ ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -f $HOME/.ssh/mykey/ecdsa_key_file
```

or

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -f $HOME/.ssh/mykey/ed25519_key_file
```

Lastly, to verify the key is generated successfully:

```
$ ls -l $HOME/.ssh/mykey/
```