# How can I change the directory that ssh-keygen outputs to?

Tags: ssh, git

I want to run a command like:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"
```

My understanding is that ssh-keygen outputs to the home directory. I'm working on a networked computer using Git Bash (Windows, MYSS MINGW64) where the home directory is one I don't have access to. I change the home directory like so:

```
export HOME=C:/Users/myusername
```

so now when I enter:

```
echo $HOME
```

it says:

```
C:/Users/myusername
```

but when I again try to run the ssh-keygen command it runs in the directory that I don't have access to. I've looked through the profile file for some hard coded path but can't find anything. How do I change it to point to a directory that I do have access to?

Comment: This same behavior happens on Ubuntu (changing `HOME` doesn't affect the default directory for `ssh-keygen`). Though specifying the directory explicitly works, I'd be interested to know why `ssh-keygen` doesn't just use `$HOME/.ssh` as `HOME` is currently defined.

Answer (score 182, accepted):

You should be able to do this by specifying the name of the output file with the `-f` option, e.g.,

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com" -f $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Of course, it really helps if the output directory has already been created.

For further reading:

- [tutorial](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/) (already alluded to, but omitting this informat)
- [manual page for ssh-keygen](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/ssh-keygen.1?query=ssh-keygen&sec=1)
- *[ssh-keygen -f confusion](https://superuser.com/questions/317608/ssh-keygen-f-confusion)* (create the directory first)
- *[Linux / Unix ssh-keygen: Create A Host Key File](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-unix-bsd-appleosx-generate-ssh-hostkeys/)* (example of `-f` usage)

Comment: Much obliged. I overlooked the -f option. I just created a new folder with mkdir .ssh in my HOME and ran the command you said. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10:

From the accepted answer, $HOME did not work for me for the path, but %userprofile% does:

```
ssh-keygen -f %userprofile%/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: When using the -f in Windows, $HOME does not work from the above answer but %userprofile% does work.

Answer (score 0):

For me you should use this option -f  like this :

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -f /home/user/project/ssh-keys/id_ras
```

And finally sh-keygen generate two file private and public into this directory

```
/home/user/project/ssh-keys/id_ras
/home/user/project/ssh-keys/id_ras.pub
```